# My Proof for the Inverse Function Theorem

Tags: real-analysis, solution-verification

Here's what I want to prove:

Let $f: (a,b) \to \mathbb{R}$ be a continuous injection, let $y_0 \in f[(a,b)]$ and let $f^{-1}: f[(a,b)] \to (a,b)$ be the inverse. Suppose that $f$ is differentiable at $x_0 = f^{-1}(y_0)$ so that $f'(x_0) \neq 0$. Then, $f^{-1}$ is differentiable at $y_0$ and:

$$(f^{-1})'(y_0) = \frac{1}{f'(x_0)}$$

---

Proof Attempt:

We know that $f[(a,b)]$ is an interval since $f$ is continuous and that $f^{-1}$ is a continuous injection. Without loss of generality, assume that $f$ is strictly increasing. Then, $f^{-1}$ is strictly increasing. Then, we are told that the following limit exists:

$$f'(x_0) = \lim_{x \to x_0} \frac{f(x)-f(x_0)}{x-x_0}$$

$$\implies f'(x_0) = \lim_{x \to f^{-1}(y_0)} \frac{f(x)-y_0}{x-f^{-1}(y_0)}$$

Let $y = f(x)$. Since $f: (a,b) \to f[(a,b)]$ is a bijection, $f^{-1}(y) = x$. So, we now have:

$$f'(x_0) = \lim_{x \to f^{-1}(y_0)} \frac{y-y_0}{f^{-1}(y)-f^{-1}(y_0)}$$

The above is equivalent to the following predicate:

$$\forall \epsilon > 0: \exists \delta > 0: x \in (f^{-1}(y_0)-\delta,f^{-1}(y_0)+\delta) \setminus \{f^{-1}(y_0)\} \implies \left| \frac{y-y_0}{f^{-1}(y)-f^{-1}(y_0)} - f'(x_0) \right| < \epsilon$$

Then, since $f$ is a strictly increasing continuous function, it follows that:

$$x \in ((f^{-1}(y_0)-\delta,f^{-1}(y_0)+\delta) \setminus \{f^{-1}(y_0)\}$$

$$\iff y = f(x) \in (f(f^{-1}(y_0)-\delta),f(f^{-1}(y_0)+\delta)) \setminus \{y_0 \}$$

which implies that $y \in (y_0-\delta',y_0+\delta')$ for some $\delta' > 0$. So, in fact, we have shown that the following statement holds:

$$\forall \epsilon > 0: \exists \delta' > 0: 0 < |y-y_0| < \delta' \implies \left| \frac{y-y_0}{f^{-1}(y)-f^{-1}(y_0)} - f'(x_0) \right| < \epsilon$$

However, that means that:

$$\lim_{y \to y_0} \frac{y-y_0}{f^{-1}(y)-f^{-1}(y_0)} = f'(x_0) \neq 0$$

which further implies that:

$$\frac{1}{f'(x_0)} = \frac{1}{\lim_{y \to y_0} \frac{y-y_0}{f^{-1}(y)-f^{-1}(y_0)}} = \lim_{y \to y_0} \frac{1}{\frac{y-y_0}{f^{-1}(y)-f^{-1}(y_0)}} = \lim_{y \to y_0} \frac{f^{-1}(y)-f^{-1}(y_0)}{y-y_0} = (f^{-1})'(y_0)$$

as was desired. $\Box$

Does the proof above work? If it doesn't, then why? How can I fix it?

Comment: Bump, I would still like to have my proof verified haha

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your proof works fine, in my opinion it just lacks two details:

1. You could add some more information about why $f[(a,b)]$ is an interval and why $f$ must be a strictly monotonic function. Both of these facts are consequences of the Intermediate Value Theorem.
2. You should be more careful in the passage with $\delta'$. Although the conclusion is true the argument was wrong. You say that "$y\in(f(f^{-1}(y_0)-\delta),f(f^{-1}(y_0)+\delta))\setminus \{y_0\}$ implies that $y\in (y_0-\delta', y_0 + \delta')$ for some $\delta'>0$", which is not wrong, but notice that, in the next passage, when you conclude that
   $$\forall \epsilon > 0: \exists \delta' > 0: 0 < |y-y_0| < \delta' \implies \left| \frac{y-y_0}{f^{-1}(y)-f^{-1}(y_0)} - f'(x_0) \right| < \epsilon,
   $$
   you are actually using the reverse implication, which is that "$y\in (y_0-\delta', y_0 + \delta')\setminus \{y_0\}$ implies $y\in(f(f^{-1}(y_0)-\delta),f(f^{-1}(y_0)+\delta))\setminus \{y_0\}$", not the one you stated.

Of course this can be fixed by something like:
$$
x \in (f^{-1}(y_0)-\delta,f^{-1}(y_0)+\delta) \setminus \{f^{-1}(y_0)\} \iff y\in(f(f^{-1}(y_0)-\delta),f(f^{-1}(y_0)+\delta))\setminus \{y_0\},
$$
and since $f(f^{-1}(y_0)-\delta)< y_0<f(f^{-1}(y_0)+\delta)$ there exists $\delta'>0$ such that
$$
y\in (y_0-\delta', y_0 + \delta')\setminus \{y_0\}\ \ \Rightarrow\ \ y\in(f(f^{-1}(y_0)-\delta),f(f^{-1}(y_0)+\delta))\setminus \{y_0\}.
$$

Comment: Thank you very much, I see where i may have goofed up a little bit.

Comment: Hmm okay, the thing is, $f[(a,b)]$ being an interval is just a previously proven result I'm using about continuous functions. $f$ being strictly monotonous follows from the injectivity of the function. I'll prove that. So, if $f$ is injective in the interval $I$, then $f(x) = f(y) \implies x = y$. In other words, if $x < y$, then $f(x) \neq f(y)$ so $f(x) < f(y)$ or $f(x) > f(y)$. We get a similar result when $x > y$. I don't think we have to use the Intermediate Value Theorem for that specifically.

Comment: We can't take off the continuity. Indeed, whenever $x<y$, injectiveness implies that either $f(x)<f(y)$ or $f(x)>f(y)$, but this fact does not ensure that it will be always "$<$" or always "$>$". In fact, when $f$ is not continuous, "$<$" and"$>$" could change. As an example, consider the function $f(x)= x$, if $x\in(0,1/2]$ and $f(x)= 3/2 - x$, if $x\in(1/2,1)$. It is injective, strictly increasing in $(0,1/2]$ and strictly decreasing in $(1/2,1)$.

Comment: Ohhhh okay okay that makes sense. Thank you very much

Comment: Even locally, we can't guarantee anything. For instance, any neighborhood U of the point $1/2$ will have parts where $f$ is strictly increasing and parts where it is strictly decreasing, so $f$ is neither increasing or decreasing in $U$. And indeed the point $1/2$ is the only one where the continuity fails.

Comment: An idea on how to use I.V.T. to prove that. The key is to prove the following claim: whenever $x<y<z$, we must have either $f(x)<f(y)<f(z)$ or $f(x)>f(y)>f(z)$. Indeed, if we had $f(x), f(z)< f(y)$, then, by fixing $a\in(\max\{f(x),f(z)\},f(y))$, by the I.V.T., we find $u\in (x,y)$ and $v\in (y,z)$ such that $f(u)=f(v)=a$, which is a contradiction with the injectiveness. Using the same idea, we prove that $f(x), f(z) > f(y)$ can't happen either, only lasting the possibilities $f(x)<f(y)<f(z)$ and $f(x)>f(y)>f(z)$. And the Claim is proved. Now it's just a matter of using the Claim wisely.

Answer (score 1):

It might be easier to do the following:

Let $g = f^{-1}$, we have $g(f(x)) = x$.
Suppose $t_n \to t=f(x_0)$, then (for sufficiently large $n$) we can find $x_n$ such that $t_n = f(x_n)$. Futhermore, we have $x_n \to x_0$.
Then ${g(t_n)-g(t) \over t_n-t} = {x_n -x_0 \over f(x_n)-f(x_0)} \to {1 \over f'(x_0)}$.

Comment: +1 Yes, that's how my book approached it (I looked at the proof it gave after I posted my own attempt above). Do you have any specific comments about my proof? So, maybe comments about clarity or any dodgy steps that i should've justified (aside from the ones mentioned above by Andre).